# print without Parenthesis instruction in Python 3, in the spyder IDE, prints the instruction 3 times, instead of a Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

When using print instruction without Parenthesis in Python 3 in the Spyder Ide, it prints the print instruction 3 times with an arrow "------>", and then it prints the string

[image]

Comment: i think it's telling you not to use `print` as a statement (as was done in python 2)

Comment: It's interesting it even works. A "vanilla" python interpreter simply throws a syntax error.

Comment: @rv.kvetch, that what I thought too, but it in a normal python interpreter, it should return a syntax error, i just checked, this interpreter was is a part of the whole anoncanda download, maybe the interpreter is modified or something

Comment: @white exactly, I suspect its a modified interpreter, it s a part of the whole anoncanda download